# How to start a server via Jenkins without outputting the server trace in the Jenkins console?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, tomcat, jenkins

I have written a windows batch script to start an apache tomcat server via Jenkins. When the server starts to run, server trace is shown in the Jenkins console. But all on a sudden the window of the server closes saying **Process leaked file descriptors** in Jenkins console. Why does that happen? Is there a way to run the batch script without outputting the server trace in the Jenkins console?

Answer (score 1):

1. To mute server trace, you can redirect output from your bat to NUL. Example:
   your.bat > NUL 2>&1
   You can find more about redirecting output on Windows here:
   http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php
2. Your second problem with Jenkins seems to an expected behaviour. You can find more explanation in the official Jenkins wiki, here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build Note the information in the blue box - that is the error you are getting.

I presume you are either trying to start your server using a build Action (Execute Windows Batch Command) or a post-build step. This makes it an integral part of your build, thus blocking it from completing. For this purpose you should try using the Batch Tasks Plugin for Jenkins, since it will not block your build. Your build will finish successfully, and the task will run separately.